# R: If one column is populated, what are the next most common columns that are also populated?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   LOS   RFG   TMV   SHN   QRE   TES   KLO  
1    0     0     3     0     0     4    28
2    1     0     0     9     0     0     0
3    0     0    39    98     0     0     0
4    2     0     0    10     0     0     0
5    0     0     7     5     0     0     0
6    0     0     0     0     0     2     6
7    0     2     3     9     0     3     0
```

I want to figure out which columns are also populated with values greater than 0 when a certain column is populated with values greater than 0, but I'm having trouble figuring this one out. I tried to use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(LOS,RFG,TMV,SHN,QRE,TES,KLO) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  slice(which.max(n)) %>%
  select(-n)
```

but it's not working correctly. Maybe I should use aggregate? Basically I want to return the names of columns that commonly have values greater than 0 across rows.

Ideally I'd like to figure out how to get R to return something like this

```
LOS: SHN
RFG: TMV, SHN, TES 
SHN: LOS, TMV, RFG, TES

etc.
```

I'm pretty new to R so I'm not sure if this is even possible, or if there is a better way to get a similar result but I would really appreciate any insight.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

UPDATE:
The answers are great- but is there a way to order the returned column names by the numbers populating the columns rather than alphabetically, specifically from largest values to smallest?

Comment: Please include your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setNames(object = lapply(1:NCOL(df), function(i)
    unique(colnames(df)[-i][which(as.matrix(df[which(df[,i] > 0), -i]) > 0,
                                  arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]])),
    nm = colnames(df))
#$LOS
#[1] "SHN"

#$RFG
#[1] "TMV" "SHN" "TES"

#$TMV
#[1] "RFG" "SHN" "TES" "KLO"

#$SHN
#[1] "LOS" "RFG" "TMV" "TES"

#$QRE
#character(0)

#$TES
#[1] "RFG" "TMV" "SHN" "KLO"

#$KLO
#[1] "TMV" "TES"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)

dat <- fread('LOS   RFG   TMV   SHN   QRE   TES   KLO  
    0     0     3     0     0     4    28
                 1     0     0     9     0     0     0
                 0     0    39    98     0     0     0
                 2     0     0    10     0     0     0
                 0     0     7     5     0     0     0
                 0     0     0     0     0     2     6
                 0     2     3     9     0     3     0')

dat_names <- names(dat)

funky <- function(x) {
  res <- apply(dat[get(x) > 0], 2, function(y) length(y[y > 0]))
  vals <- names(res[res > 0])
  vals[!vals == x]
}

sapply(dat_names, funky)
```

Result:

```
# $LOS
# [1] "SHN"
# 
# $RFG
# [1] "TMV" "SHN" "TES"
# 
# $TMV
# [1] "RFG" "SHN" "TES" "KLO"
# 
# $SHN
# [1] "LOS" "RFG" "TMV" "TES"
# 
# $QRE
# character(0)
# 
# $TES
# [1] "RFG" "TMV" "SHN" "KLO"
# 
# $KLO
# [1] "TMV" "TES"
```

Answer (score 0):

First I build an unnamed list with the relevant content, but including zeroes, then I remove the zero values and name the list

```
res <- lapply(seq_along(df1),function(x){df1 %>% subset(df1[x]!=0) %>% select(-x) %>% colSums}) %>%
   lapply(function(x){names(x[x>0])}) %>% setNames(names(df1))
# $LOS
# [1] "SHN"
# 
# $RFG
# [1] "TMV" "SHN" "TES"
# 
# $TMV
# [1] "RFG" "SHN" "TES" "KLO"
# 
# $SHN
# [1] "LOS" "RFG" "TMV" "TES"
# 
# $QRE
# character(0)
# 
# $TES
# [1] "RFG" "TMV" "SHN" "KLO"
# 
# $KLO
# [1] "TMV" "TES"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df <- data.frame(LOS=c(0,1,0,2,0,0,0),
                 RFG=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,2),
                 TMV=c(3,0,39,0,7,0,3),
                 SHN=c(0,9,98,10,5,0,9),
                 QRE=rep(0,7),
                 TES=c(4,0,0,0,0,2,3),
                 KLO=c(28,0,0,0,0,6,0))
```

Remove columns from `df` that have all 0s.

```
library(dplyr)
library(iterators)
df1 <- df %>% select_if(function(col) mean(col)>0)
```

Use `icount` as iterator and `dplyr` verbs to reduce the data frame to relevant rows and columns.

```
 l1 <- lapply(icount(ncol(df1)), function(x) df1 %>% 
                                               filter(df1[,x]>0) %>% 
                                               select_if(function(col) mean(col)>0) %>% 
                                               select(-1) %>% 
                                               colnames())
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "SHN"

[[2]]
[1] "TMV" "SHN" "TES"

[[3]]
[1] "TMV" "SHN" "TES" "KLO"

[[4]]
[1] "RFG" "TMV" "SHN" "TES"

[[5]]
[1] "TMV" "SHN" "TES" "KLO"

[[6]]
[1] "TES" "KLO"
```